# How to build a multi-module maven project in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a projects structure as follows:

```
ProjectParent
 - pom.xml
 ProjectApp
   -pom.xml
 ProjectAPI
   -pom.xml
 ProjectModels
   -pom.xml
 ProjectServices
   -pom.xml
 Etc..
```

`ProjectModels/ProjectsServices` are dependencies within `ProjectAPI/ProjectApp`.

1. Should I create separate jobs within Jenkins to build each module separately?
2. I created a job for `ProjectAPP` but get the following error below (Have set goals and actions to "clean install":

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>       [INFO]
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] Building myproject-app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
> Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/myproject/myproject-common-config/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-common-config-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
> [WARNING] The POM for com.myproject:myproject-common-config:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing,
> ```
>
> no dependency information available
>       Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/myproject/myproject-entities/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-entities-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       [WARNING] The POM for com.myproject:myproject-entities:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>       Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/myproject/myproject-services/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       [WARNING] The POM for com.myproject:myproject-services:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>       Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/myproject/myproject-persistence/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       [WARNING] The POM for com.myproject:myproject-persistence:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>       Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/myproject/myproject-common-config/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-common-config-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>       ......
>       org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project myproject-app: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project com.myproject:myproject-app:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.myproject:myproject-common-config:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   com.myproject:myproject-entities:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   com.myproject:myproject-services:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   com.myproject:myproject-persistence:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact com.myproject:myproject-common-config:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in
>   org.springframework.maven.snapshot
>   (http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot)

ProjectParent Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>myproject-entities</module>
        <module>myproject-services</module>
        <module>myproject-persistence</module>
        <module>myproject-app</module>
        <module>myproject-merchant</module>
        <module>myproject-common-config</module>
        <module>myproject-api</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>      
        ...
    </repositories>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

    <properties>
        ...

        <myproject-entities-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-entities-version>
        <myproject-services-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-services-version>
        <myproject-persistence-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-persistence-version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

ProjectApp Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>myproject-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproject-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>

        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-common-config</artifactId>
            <version>${myproject-common-config}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-entities</artifactId>
            <version>${myproject-entities-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-services</artifactId>
            <version>${myproject-services-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${myproject-persistence-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <myproject-common-config>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-common-config>
        <myproject-entities-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-entities-version>
        <myproject-services-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-services-version>
        <myproject-persistence-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</myproject-persistence-version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Am I using the wrong goals? Do I need to chain a number of commands? i.e. build other modules first?

I'm using Maven 3.

NOTE: I changed the target to "clean install" against the ParentProject Pom and everything builds correctly.

Thanks

Comment: have you specified all the other modules in the parent pom `<modules>` section? If so, this should work. If not, you should do that.

Comment: Could you please post the `pom.xml` for the `ProjectAPP`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you can't create a project solely for the `ProjectApp` module because it depends on the other modules below the `ProjectApp` parent. If you don't deploy those modules to your maven repository, maven is not able to find them in the repository nor in the build reactor.

Instead you should create the job for the parent. This will build the necessary modules.

You may also work with the option [`also-make-dependants`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) when you have a job for `ProjectApp`, but I haven't any experience with this.

Comment: Thanks SpaceTrucker. I have created the job for the parent as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and SpaceTrucker answer helped me.

Hence I just run something like:

`.../ProjectParent$ mvn -am -pl ProjectApp test`