# how to trigger Jenkins job based on the modifications in svn modules with out incremental build

Tags: maven, jenkins

we have a lot of modules each time when we are building all modules, though we are not modified any thing on another modules...

when we run the root pom, it will build and gather all the assemblies in our own defined folder structure including jars and some kind of scripts to deploy...allt he scripts and configuration xml's we kept on one folder in svn, at the time of assembling we gather all the jar's + scripts....

for this we created a 3 profiles based on the need

let say

```
profile 1 ----> <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
        <module>c</module>

profile 2 ----> <module>x</module>
        <module>y</module>
        <module>z</module>

 profile 3 ----> <module>x</module>
        <module>y</module>
        <module>z</module>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
        <module>c</module>
```

in maven perspective if we knows if a is changed we will run profile1 and x is changed profile2...to reduce the build time.

in jenkins by using parameeters build we can achieve this...

**quetions:-**
1) each time we have manually run the jenkins job by selecting the property
 is there any way to automate based on chnges...
lets say a was changed it has to run profile1 automatically.

Comment: Why don't you build everything when there is a change in any module?  How long would that take?  Wouldn't that be simpler than this?  The alternate is to have a job for each module and use `-am` flag to build dependant modules.  See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136514/how-to-build-a-multi-module-maven-project-in-jenkins)

Comment: 1)now we are building all the modules...its is taking 1 hr time. 2) we want to rebuild only some set of modules from root pom thats why we are thinking to go for as mentioned...is there any best approach in this situation